# How do i embed only certain parts of my R command into R markdown document using `r `?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am creating a hypothesis test and confidence interval using this command:

````
```{r}
t.test(urtak1$fermetraverd ~ urtak1$matssvaedi)
```
````

And I need to embed the t-value and p-value as well as the confidence interval (seperately) into text for my R markdown document. How do I do this using ' r ' ?

Here is my output:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  urtak1$fermetraverd by urtak1$matssvaedi
t = 1.0812, df = 96.784, p-value = 0.2823
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -12.02648  40.80856
sample estimates:
   mean in group Hagar mean in group Kringlan 
          348.5697               334.1787
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `broom` package. I do not have the data you are using your questione, so I set up something quickly with `iris`.

In a first chunk you do the analysis and create an object that holds the "tidy" version of your t-test output. For example

````
```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

example <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  droplevels()

result <- t.test(example$Sepal.Length ~ example$Species)

tidy_result <- tidy(result)

```
````

Have a look at `tidy_result`: the magic of the broom package is that it extracts all the output of your t-test (and many others!) in a tidy dataframe, that you can use elsewhere.

Now you can use this in your text, evaluating `r tidy_result$statistic` to show your t-statistic and `r tidy_result$p.value` to show your p-value (the back-ticks are not showing correctly, but should be placed in front of the 'r' expressions in  with the tidy_result objects.

In your Rmarkdown it might look like this:

```
the t-test resulted in a t-statistic of `r tidy_result$statistic` 
with a p-value of `r tidy_result$p.value`
```

To look at all the parameters you can include, evaluate `tidy_result` in your console. You will see:

```
> tidy_result
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic      p.value parameter   conf.low  conf.high                  method alternative
1   -0.652     5.936     6.588 -5.629165 1.866144e-07  94.02549 -0.8819731 -0.4220269 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

So you can choose any of the following:

```
"estimate"    "estimate1"   "estimate2"   
"statistic"   "p.value"     "parameter"    
"conf.low"    "conf.high"   "method"      "alternative"
```

Notice that your to get your confidence interval, you have the low (`conf.low`) and the high (`conf.high`) value at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I have not figured out how to embed the confidence interval into Rmarkdown yet, i tried `r tidy_result$conf.int` without any luck.

Comment: There is no value called `conf.int` in the tidy_result data.frame. But you do have access to the low and high boundaries of your confidence interval directly. I've update the question to make it more clear what you have available to work with after using broom.